# Databinding failing in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have been trying to create a small application to sit over a POS interface and allow the user to access some information not accessible through the standard POS software by external custom C# applications. One of these was a receipt lookup, which after a demonstration was asked to be expanded to also check online order details.

The problem I am having is with the databinding to the object which is storing the information. Originally when there was a single view and viewmodel for the function it worked correctly. After creating 2 usercontrol views to present different information, with corresponding viewmodels for each view, the new views do not show any data.

Here is the base class inherited by the Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RGLibrary
{
    public abstract class Observable_Object : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }

        #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        #region Debugging Aides

        /// <summary>
        /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
        /// a public property with the specified name. This
        /// method does not exist in a Release build.
        /// </summary>
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public virtual void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            // Verify that the property name matches a real,
            // public, instance property on this object.
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
            {
                string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

                if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                else
                    Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
        /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
        /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might
        /// override this property's getter to return true.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

        #endregion // Debugging Aides
    }
}
```

The inherited class by the VMs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace RGLibrary
{
    public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(member, val))
                return false;

            member = val;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the core VM class:

```
using RGLibrary;
using Store_Launcher.Model;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Store_Launcher.ViewModel
{
    public class ReceiptLookupVM: BindableBase
    {
        private string _ReceiptNumber;
        private ReceiptLookupModel _ReceiptDetails;
        public ReceiptLookupModel ReceiptDetails
        {
            get { return _ReceiptDetails; }
            set { _ReceiptDetails = value; OnPropertyChanged("ReceiptDetails"); }
        }
        public RGDBConnect rms = new RGDBConnect("");
        public string ReceiptNumber
        {
            get { return _ReceiptNumber; }
            set { _ReceiptNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("ReceiptNumber"); }
        }

        private OnlineOrderDetailsVM orderDetailsVM = new OnlineOrderDetailsVM();
        private ReceiptDetailsVM receiptDetailsVM = new ReceiptDetailsVM();

        private BindableBase _CurrentMode;
        public BindableBase CurrentMode
        {
            get { return _CurrentMode; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _CurrentMode, value); }
        }



        public ReceiptLookupVM()
        {
            ReceiptDetails = new ReceiptLookupModel();
            ReceiptNumber = "";
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                rms = new RGDBConnect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rmstest"]);
            else
                rms = new RGDBConnect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rms"]);
            CheckCommand = new MyICommand<string>(OnCheck);
            CurrentMode = receiptDetailsVM;
        }
        public MyICommand<string> CheckCommand { get; private set; }
        private void OnCheck(string command)
        {
            ReceiptDetails.Receipt = _ReceiptNumber;

            string query = "rg_launcher_receiptref_ext '" + ReceiptDetails.Receipt + "'";
            try
            {
                DataTable results = rms.ExecuteSelect(query);
                if (results.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    DataRow resultRow = results.Rows[0];
                    if (resultRow["tran_type"].ToString() == "SALE")
                    {
                        ReceiptDetails.SaleCode = resultRow["sale_code"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Customer = resultRow["name"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.CustomerID = resultRow["customer_id"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Items = resultRow["units"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Value = resultRow["value"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Stylist = resultRow["stylist"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.TransactionType = ReceiptLookupModel.TransType.RetailOrder;
                        receiptDetailsVM.UpdateDetails(ReceiptDetails);
                        CurrentMode = receiptDetailsVM;
                    }
                    else if (resultRow["tran_type"].ToString() == "WEB ORDER")
                    {
                        ReceiptDetails.SaleCode = resultRow["sale_code"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.ReceiptNumber = resultRow["receipt_ref"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Customer = resultRow["name"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.CustomerID = resultRow["customer_id"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Items = resultRow["units"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.Value = resultRow["value"].ToString();
                        ReceiptDetails.TransactionType = ReceiptLookupModel.TransType.OnlineOrder;
                        orderDetailsVM.UpdateDetails(ReceiptDetails);
                        CurrentMode = orderDetailsVM;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            "Unable to determine the transaction type for this number. Please contact IT for assistance",
                            "Receipt Lookup: Unknown order number",
                            MessageBoxButton.OK,
                            MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                        ReceiptDetails = new ReceiptLookupModel();
                        receiptDetailsVM.UpdateDetails(ReceiptDetails);
                        CurrentMode = receiptDetailsVM;
                    }
                }
                else if (results.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "Unable to find this receipt number in the system. Please make sure that the receipt number has been entered correctly.",
                        "Receipt Lookup: Unable to find sale",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK,
                        MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                    ReceiptDetails = new ReceiptLookupModel();
                    receiptDetailsVM.UpdateDetails(ReceiptDetails);
                    CurrentMode = receiptDetailsVM;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                        "An error has occured and the system is unable to properly locate this receipt number in the system. Please contact IT for assistance",
                        "Receipt Lookup: Unable to find sale",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK,
                        MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    ReceiptDetails = new ReceiptLookupModel();
                    receiptDetailsVM.UpdateDetails(ReceiptDetails);
                    CurrentMode = receiptDetailsVM;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    e.Message,
                    "Receipt Lookup: An error has occurred",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "An error has occured and the system is unable to properly locate this receipt number in the system. Please check to make sure your computer is currently connected to the internet. Contact IT for further assistance",
                    "Receipt Lookup: Unable to lookup receipt number",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                ReceiptDetails = new ReceiptLookupModel();
                receiptDetailsVM.UpdateDetails(ReceiptDetails);
                CurrentMode = receiptDetailsVM;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding view:

```
<Window x:Class="Store_Launcher.Views.ReceiptLookupView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Store_Launcher.Views"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Store_Launcher.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Rodd &amp; Gunn Launcher: Receipt Lookup" Height="195" Width="450"
        ShowInTaskbar="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:ReceiptLookupVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:OnlineOrderDetailsVM}">
            <local:OnlineOrderDetailsView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:ReceiptDetailsVM}">
            <local:ReceiptDetailsView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                        Executed="CloseCommandHandler"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="5"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Receipt Number: "/>
            <TextBox Width="100"
                     Text="{Binding ReceiptNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- New User Control XAML to switch between brick and mortar, and online order modes -->

        <UserControl
            Margin="5"
            Height="115"
            Width="230"
            Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentMode}"/>
        </UserControl>

        <!-- Original Grid XAML -->

        <!--<Grid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Margin="5"
              DataContext="{Binding ReceiptDetails}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Sale Code: "/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding SaleCode}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Customer ID:  "/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding CustomerID}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Customer: "/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Customer}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Items: "/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Items}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Value: "/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Stylist: "/>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Stylist}"/>
        </Grid>-->

        <StackPanel
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button
                Width="100"
                Height="20"
                Margin="5"
                Content="CHECK"
                Command="{Binding CheckCommand}"/>
            <Button
                Width="100"
                Height="20"
                Margin="5"
                Content="CLOSE"
                Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the order details model:

```
using RGLibrary;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Store_Launcher.Model
{
    public class ReceiptLookupModel: Observable_Object
    {
        private string _Receipt;
        private string _SaleCode;
        private string _ReceiptNumber;
        private string _CustomerID;
        private string _Customer;
        private string _Items;
        private string _Value;
        private string _Stylist;
        private TransType? _TransactionType;
        public string Receipt
        {
            get { return _Receipt = (_Receipt ?? ""); }
            set { _Receipt = value; OnPropertyChanged("Receipt"); }
        }
        public string SaleCode
        {
            get { return _SaleCode = (_SaleCode ?? ""); }
            set { _SaleCode = value; OnPropertyChanged("SaleCode"); }
        }
        public string ReceiptNumber
        {
            get { return _ReceiptNumber = (_ReceiptNumber ?? ""); }
            set { _ReceiptNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("ReceiptNumber"); }
        }
        public string CustomerID
        {
            get { return _CustomerID = (_CustomerID ?? ""); }
            set { _CustomerID = value; OnPropertyChanged("CustomerID"); }
        }
        public string Customer
        {
            get { return _Customer = (_Customer ?? ""); }
            set { _Customer = value; OnPropertyChanged("Customer"); }
        }
        public string Items
        {
            get { return _Items = (_Items ?? "0"); }
            set { _Items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get { return _Value = (_Value ?? "$0.00"); }
            set { _Value = value; OnPropertyChanged("Value"); }
        }
        public string Stylist
        {
            get { return _Stylist = (_Stylist ?? ""); }
            set { _Stylist = value; OnPropertyChanged("Stylist"); }
        }
        public TransType? TransactionType
        {
            get { return _TransactionType = (_TransactionType ?? TransType.None); }
            set { _TransactionType = value; OnPropertyChanged("TransactionType"); }
        }


        public enum TransType
        {
            OnlineOrder,
            RetailOrder,
            None
        }
    }
}
```

The online orders viewmodel:

```
using RGLibrary;
using Store_Launcher.Model;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Store_Launcher.ViewModel
{
    public class OnlineOrderDetailsVM: BindableBase
    {
        private ReceiptLookupModel _OrderDetails;
        public ReceiptLookupModel OrderDetails
        {
            get { return _OrderDetails; }
            set { _OrderDetails = value; OnPropertyChanged("OrderDetails"); }
        }
        public OnlineOrderDetailsVM()
        {
            OrderDetails = new ReceiptLookupModel();
        }

        public void UpdateDetails(ReceiptLookupModel SQLData)
        {
            ReceiptLookupModel _data = new ReceiptLookupModel();
            _data.Customer = SQLData.Customer;
            _data.CustomerID = SQLData.CustomerID;
            _data.Items = SQLData.Items;
            _data.Receipt = SQLData.Receipt;
            _data.ReceiptNumber = SQLData.Receipt;
            _data.SaleCode = SQLData.SaleCode;
            _data.Stylist = SQLData.Stylist;
            _data.TransactionType = SQLData.TransactionType;
            _data.Value = SQLData.Value;
            OrderDetails = _data;

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the order details view:

```
<UserControl x:Name="OnlineOrderDetailsUC"
             x:Class="Store_Launcher.Views.OnlineOrderDetailsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Store_Launcher.Views"  
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Store_Launcher.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="115" d:DesignWidth="230">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:OnlineOrderDetailsVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Margin="5"
          DataContext="{Binding OrderDetails, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Sale Code: "/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding SaleCode}"/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Receipt No:  "/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding ReceiptNumber}"/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Customer ID:  "/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding CustomerID}"/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Customer: "/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Customer}"/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Items: "/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Items}"/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="Value: "/>
        <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="5"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Value}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The thing I am confused about is that in the receiptLookup view, when I use the commented out grid instead of usercontrol section that binds to the model object in the receiptLookup viewmodel correctly but the usercontrol binding does not seem to work.

I have tried a number of things to resolve this. Originally instead of using a method inside the orderdetails viewmodel to set the model's object value I was just setting it to be the same as the one generated in the receiptlookup viewmodel.

In addition I have tried to use diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High in the binding to diagnose if there is a binding error based on other questions that have been asked previously. I think that it is binding to something because there is no error about the binding failing, and it lists a hash for an object that is binding to.

Further to this I have tried to remove the datacontext from both the orderdetails view's usercontrol and also from the datagrid's datacontext, and specify it in the binding path but that did not change any results either.

Another question was given the advice to add an x:name to their views, so I have done the same without any changes. I have also tried adding NotifyOnSourceUpdate=True to each textblock's binding and Mode=TwoWay but neither on their own or the combination of both has helped.

I have used a similar usercontrol sub-section of the main view in a few previous applications at this point so I am really quite stuck as to why it is not working in this case. I have tried to add all the relevant code but if you need me to list anything else please let me know in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a UserControl in a DataTemplate like

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:OnlineOrderDetailsVM}">
    <local:OnlineOrderDetailsView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

the UserControl is supposed to inherit its DataContext from its parent object, which is a ContentControl or a ContentPresenter here. The DataContext holds an instance of the type specified by the DataTemplate's `DataType` property (i.e. the `Content` of the ContentControl or ContentPresenter).

This [property value inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance) only works if you do not explicity set the property, as in

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:OnlineOrderDetailsVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This DataContext value has higher precedence than the inherited value. The result is that the UserControl in the DataTemplate always binds to its private DataContext object, but never to the one provided by the template.

So just remove the DataContext assignment from the UserControl's XAML. Controls should never explicitly set their own DataContext, hence never have private view model objects.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something simple like this. Thank you for the solution and explanation!